# Bash Script to backup and restore directory structure

Tags: linux, bash, script, tar

Basically I have this directory structure in Linux.

```
Backup
 Dir_1 
     Sub_Dir_1
          file_1  90 GB
          file_2  10 GB
     Sub_Dir_2
          file_1  20 GB

Restore
 Dir_1
     Sub_Dir_1
         file_1 0 bytes
         file_2 0 bytes
     Sub_Dir_2
         file_1 0 bytes
```

And the list goes on.
I can tar the whole directory but that would take a while because of the file sizes of the files inside each sub directory.

What I want is to create a script that will backup the whole directory structure and be able to restore the same directory on different computer but with all files inside the sub directory zeroed out.
All I want is their directory name and file names. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. Take a minute to read [ask], and maybe how to format the question, so that you can help people to better answer you. How complex is your directory structure, and  which is the number of files (1 10 100 1000 10000...1M) ? You can [edit] your post to complete the question.

Comment: One important difference is if you need or not to preserve timestamp ownership and attributes for each file/directory.

Comment: a workaround but if you're a big linux bash wiz then you could install cygwin on windows and write a linux bash script to do it

Comment: @barlop I suppose he already is under Linux...

Comment: @oLiVeR:... and so? did you try the solution? did it worked for you? Give some feedback.

Answer (score 0):

#### Divide in sub-problem

In general when you cannot find a fast complete solution to your problem you can divide it in sub-problems more easy to be solved.

- A way is to create **a `tar` file of the directory structure and a `list of files`** to be touched inside the directory structure that you can compress after. You do not need to create the whole directory structure and you will have only two files.
  With the `touch` command<sup>[[1](http://ss64.com/bash/touch.html)]</sup> you can update the modification time of a file, and if not exists you will create an empty one(`!`). After you have created the copy of the directory structure you can *touch* the files inside.

  This script can create the files (tar+txt) in your current directory.

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  HomeDir=$(pwd)
  BackupDIR="Backup"      # Change here

  TarFileName="$HomeDir/Directory_Structure.tar"
  ListFileName="$HomeDir/File_List.txt"

  cd "$BackupDIR"

  tar -cf "$TarFileName"  --no-recursion --files-from <(find . -type d)
  find . -type f -exec echo touch \"{}\" \; > "$ListFileName"
  gzip --best "$ListFileName" "$TarFileName"    # this to compress them
  ```

  Then to extract them from the Restore directory with your two files inside you can write

  ```
  tar -zxf Directory_Structure.tar.gz
  zcat File_List.txt.gz | /bin/bash
  ```

  Note that are implicit the assumptions that you don't care of the creation time, ownership and attributes of the files, that your names are not pathological, you have no links...
- Another way is to create a **local copy of the directory and structure**. Again after that you have created the copy of the directory structure you can *touch* the files inside.
  Then you can backup all with `tar`.

  The *disadvantages* are that the original creation & modification times, ownerships and attributes  will be lost. If needed you have to put after manually, and this will complicate your script. (`touch -d "$(date -R -r filename)" Restore/filename`...)
  You will need a lot of inodes not cosy if you have *zillions* of files.

  A good point is that you can create the local directory structure copy in an intelligent way (via `tar` or `rsync` for example; with the right options it will preserve all taking care of some pathology too).
- Last but not least is to use something like the **tarfile module for python** <sup>[[2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/tarfile.html)]</sup> to create your tar file, managing each type (file and directory in a different way): be brave!